# Back to top link at bottom of company page

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

Take a look at Bose https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/bose.
They've got a pretty long company page.  They aren't the only ones with long company pages...plenty more.

Feature request, is it possible to place a **back to top** hyperlink at the bottom right of the company page anchoring me back to the top.  The scrolling is a lot!

Comment: ... just hit the Home key?

Answer (score 1):

Great point and not a hard thing to implement. We just have to make sure we're consistent throughout the site when adding new UX elements. Our team will look at this to see if/where this should be implemented. I'm not sure about timing so I'm setting it to deferred for now.